# Как получить список доступных версий Python в машиночитаемом виде? И вычислить последнюю стабильную

Tags: python, автоматизация

Есть https://devguide.python.org/versions/ , где красивая картинка. Есть https://www.python.org/downloads/ , где красивые кнопки скачивания. А мне надо аналог https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts или https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json Ткнине пожалуйста носом как мне просто узнать current версию питона.

Comment: https://www.python.org/api/v2/downloads/release/

Comment: Воу! Круто! То, что надо! Делай ответ.

Comment: @andreymal, про парсинг свойств этого апи - лучше наверное задать отдельный вопрос? Я просто пока не нашёл как мне понять, что нужно выкачивать `3.10.11`, которая на текущий момент является latest stable.

Comment: Я вижу там `"is_latest":true`

Comment: Не, латест - это `3.11.3`. А дальше, на странице загрузки идёт раздел `Stable Releases`. И вот там - `3.10.11`. Или это - тоже стабильная ветка? Я не шарю за питон.

Comment: И сразу под 3.10.11 находится та же самая 3.11.3. Предположу, что сайт сортирует версии по дате публикации, поэтому получается так странно, но 3.10.11 это всего лишь багфиксы для предыдущей стабильной версии, а самой актуальной версией всё-таки стоит считать именно 3.11.3

Comment: А, ну значит `is_latest` - таки самый нормальный вариант. Ок, спасибо. Оформи ответ, я отредактирую вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

> как мне просто узнать current версию питона.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.11.3
$
```

Если же необходимо получить все версии какого-то пакета (например - python), имеющиеся в репозитарии,  то нужно обратиться к пакетному менеджеру. Например вот так (fedora):

```
dnf info python3
```

Получим список доступных пакетов.

> Я хочу получить последнюю версию от разрабов

Здесь можно посмотреть и скачать все активные версии интерпретатора:

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Я думал, что из контекста вопроса - понятно, что в системе питона может и не быть от слова "совсем".

Comment: @donRumata - "current версию питона" - я правильно понимаю, что "current" версия - это  та, которая НЕ установлена ?

Comment: Нет. Я хочу получить последнюю (лично мне нужна стабильная, но это детали) версию от разрабов питона, а не от разрабов конкретного дистра. Если я прогружу SliTaz 10-и летней давности - там последняя версия питона будет, мягко, скажем, не сильно по-настоящему последней. Ссылки на убунту и ноду я кинул не просто так. Пройди по ним, пожалуйста и посмотри в контексте моего вопроса.